# RegEx in perl that Uses Groups to Extract Information From A Filepath

Tags: regex, perl

So I need to take something in this format: `2015-08-15_15-41-32_44100_logo.txt`and extract the date, time, and frequency from it, using these two pieces of code. Right now it's in the form `<date>_<time>_<frequency>_logo.txt.`Below is my attempt to make it a regex, but I know I'm missing something. How do I use groups in perl to do this?
The code below searches through a directory for every filepath that follows the pattern, and returns those files in a list. What I need help with is the regex itself. I need to be able to get the frequency.

```
$pattern =qr/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_44100_(\w+).(\w+)$/;
@listFiles = grep_files($bee_music_dir,$pattern);
print join(",",@listFiles);

sub grep_files {
    my ($dir, $pat) = @_;
    opendir(my $dir_handle, $dir) or die $!;
    my @files = grep { $_ =~ /$pat/ } readdir($dir_handle);
    closedir($dir_handle);
    return \@files;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expression groups in perl are used like this:

```
my ($a, $b, $c) = $somestring=~ /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/;
```

Here, each variable in the list `($a, $b, $c)` gets assigned the value of the matching groups, which are also available as `$1`, `$2`, and `$3`. So the above line is equivalent to:

```
$somestring =~ /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/;
my ($a, $b, $c) = ($1, $2, $3);
```

(you could even do `my $a = $1; my $b = $2; my $c = $3`).

If you want to declare a `$pattern` variable you should do it like this:

```
my $pattern = qr/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_(\d+)_(\w+).(\w+)/;
```

where [`qr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qr.html) is the `quote-regexp` operator, pre-compiling the regular expression for optimisation. You shouldn't use the `=~` operator here, because it would apply the regular expression to `$pattern` rather than defining `$pattern` as that regular expression.
Defining a patter this way allows you to just

```
$stringtomatch =~ $pattern;
```

(but `=~ /$pattern/` will also work).

The regular expression to match files formatted like `2015-08-15_15-41-32_44100_logo.txt` or `<date>_<time>_<frequency>_logo.txt` looks like this:

```
/^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)_(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d+)_logo\.txt$/
```

You could use `\d+` but it won't necessarily match a date. Also, `.` in regular expressions means 'any character', so if you really mean `.` you should escape it: `\.`.

Here's a more verbose version of part of your sub illustrating access to the groups:

```
my @files = ();
while ( my $file = readdir($dir_handle) ) {
   if ( my ($year,$month,$day,$hour,$minute,$second,$freq) = $file =~ $pattern ) {
       # do something with $freq
       push @files, $file;
   }
}
```

If all you are after is a list of the frequencies, it would suffice to only 'group' the wanted field:

```
my $pattern = qr/^\d+-\d+-\d+_\d+-\d+-\d+_(\d+)_logo\.txt$/;
```

Comment: So what if I wanted to make my pattern: qr/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_44100_(\w+).(\w+)$/; Where 44100 could be substituted with any frequency? Would I need to escape it too? Like \44100? If you look above at my edit, the print join(",",@listFiles); part is only printing an array address, and not the files contained in it. (If it even contains anything)

Comment: @TerikBrunson You don't need to escape the 44000, you only need to escape "special" characters, like dot, *, etc. You're getting an array reference because your grep_files is returning an array reference, not an array, so `@listFiles = grep_files...` is putting the array reference grep_files returns as the first (and only) element of the array @listFiles. Either change grep_files to return an array, or assign its return to a scalar and then use it as an array reference.

Comment: "You could use \d+ but it won't necessarily match a date." True, but neither does \d\d.

Answer (score 0):

You were close, just a few changes. Here's the script and a test run:

```
$ cat freq.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl --

use strict;
use warnings;

my $pattern = qr/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_(\d+)_(\w+).(\w+)$/;

sub grep_files {
    my ($dir, $pat) = @_;
    opendir(my $dir_handle, $dir) or die $!;
    my @files = grep { $_ =~ /$pat/ } readdir($dir_handle);
    s/$pat/$7/ foreach @files;
    closedir($dir_handle);
    \@files;
}

print join("\n", @{grep_files '.', $pattern}), "\n";
$ ls
2015-08-15_15-41-32_44100_logo.txt  freq.pl
2015-08-25_25-41-32_48000_logo.txt
$ ./freq.pl
44100
48000
```

freq.pl extracts the frequency from the filenames in the current directory. It's based on yours, with some key differences:

- You're matching the pattern against an undefined variable. You really want to store the pattern in the variable. I also anchor the pattern at the beginning and end, so in the (admittedly unlikely event in this case) you have other files with stuff at the start or end, it won't match those by accident. You were also missing a semi-colon at the end of the line.
- You were selecting the files that match the pattern, but then not extracting the frequency. The `s/$pat/$7/ foreach @files;` loops over all the files matching the pattern and replaces everything with just the 7th group, which is the frequency. You could also select files and extract the frequency in one step by using `map` instead of `grep`.
- I added the last line for testing.
- While not directly related, always use `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of your scripts. `use strict` makes some questionable constructs errors and `use warnings` warns about some possible problems with the script.

The `ls` shows the examples files in the current directory, and `freq.pl` runs the script showing the output.

Comment: Okay, I may have been unclear with one part of this then. I don't need to just extract the frequency. On each call, I need to separate and do something different with each filepath depending on its frequency. For some reason, I can't just get a list to return with all the files that match a specific pattern. Would it be possible to make my regex include a specific frequency? like qr/^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)_44100_(\w+).(\w+)$/

Comment: Your "I need to be able to get the frequency." was unclear then. :-) If you want the whole file name back from grep_files, just drop the `s/$pat/$7/ foreach @files;` and you'll get the full filename, which you can then manipulate further. You could also return both filename and frequency by returning two array references (or an array of references to two-element arrays). You could match a specific frequency by changing group 7 to just the frequency you want. There are lots of options, just depends on exactly what you want to do.